# Text and pspicture are covering eachother

Tags: minipage, physics, pspicture, drawing

I'm a beginner in drawing with LaTeX and I recently achieved to draw a super cylindric marker for my physics lectures. But ... now, trying to write the text with it, and a big problem showed up, the text and the image are covering each other...

I tried to solve with the environnement **center** with `\begin{center}` and also with `\centering` command. It didn't work, finally, I tried the `minipage` environnement with a `\vspace{...}` command, didn't work either. I Let you the image of the result and the last code with minipage. hopping that you have and idea to solve this matter.
Thank you in advance...
[image: A screen capture of the pdf file after compiling the code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-fill}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[t][6cm][t]{\linewidth}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,2)
  \psaxes[linewidth=0.2pt,arrowscale=3,ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-5,-5)(5,5)
  \pscircle(0,0){4}
  \pscircle[linestyle=dotted](0,0){2}
  \psline[linewidth=0.01,arrowscale=1.5]{->}(1,1)
  \rput(1.2,1.2){$\overrightarrow{u_r}$}
  \rput(-0.2,-0.2){\begin{large}$O$\end{large}}
  \psarc[linewidth=0.01](0,0){0.45}{0}{45}
  \rput(0.5,0.3){$\theta$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,2)` sets the dimensions of the picture to have `x` range from 0 to 3, and `y` from 0 to 2. The actual picture is much larger. So you have to change these coordinates accordingly. (tikz computes the bounding box automatically.)

Comment: Try `\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)` instead of `\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,2)`. (Or use tikz.)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked well !